# Как правильно вставлять символы юникода?

Tags: html

Везде рекомендуют использовать коды для вставки символов юникода (например `&#x2318;`). Чем этот способ лучше вставки через копирование самого символа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не все кодировки будут правильно "понимать" ваш символ, если вы его просто вставите. UTF-8, к примеру, поймёт, а вот другая какая-то может и кракозябры показать непонятные (так как у разных кодировок под одинаковыми символами могут быть разные "знаки/числа"). А юникод определяет связь между символами и "числами", он не зависит от кодировки. 
Как-то так